# sms_otp_auto_verify unable to auto detect the OTP

Tags: flutter, authentication, flutter-dependencies, one-time-password, flutter-plugin

I am using sms_otp_auto_verify this plugin in the flutter to auto-detect the OTP received on mobile and type it in the given text field.
I used this code https://pub.dev/packages/sms_otp_auto_verify/example.
But it is verifying any text that is being typed. Do I need some kind of permission? What am I missing?

Comment: It verifies the sms content when an sms arrives.

Comment: So it cannot be used for auto-detecting? @TirthPatel

Comment: I think this package auto-fills the SMS content (OTP).

Answer (score 2):

It will listen the APP Signature in the SMS, if matches then read the code (OTP) from SMS and fill it in the text field. onOtpCallback you can do the OTP validation and proceed to next screen, if success.

Working for me in debug mode not release mode

Comment: yes, unfortunately it generates different app signature in release mode and debug mode